# How to divide long text pasted in the <textarea> into paragraphs in a <div> using any magic possible?

Tags: javascript, html, text, split, paragraphs

I got a div, a `textarea`, and a `button`.

If I click the `button`,  any text inside the  `textarea` will go to the `div` mixed as a very long text **(unreadable).**

What I want is, when I click the *Go* `button`, the text would go to the `div` but split into `paragraphs` of about **200Characters**-

**PLEASE NOTE:** Split at **200th Char** if it's a *period* or Full-Stop`(.)` if not look for the next *period* after the **200th** Character.....

How can this be achieved?

Any Suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

To start with, Please see my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution to this:

```
function makeParagraphs(text){
    return '<p>' + text.replace(/(.{200}[^\.]*)(\.)+/g, '</p>$1.<p>') + '</p>';
}
```

You can test it in your example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westman/zdCyq/13/).

Comment: I choose this for simplicity though all answers WORKED perfectly... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the text and loop through all of it until you get to the end. Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/15/)

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var i = 200;
        while (theText.length > 200) {
            console.log('looping');
            while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
                i++;   
            }

            console.log(i);
            $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, i+1) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(i+1);
            i = 200;
        }

        $('#text_land').append("<p>" + theText + "</p>");
    })
})
```

Comment: AMAZING___ ! Your answer works perfectly, I give you an UPVOTE... But hope you dont mind if i choose @Hans Westman's answer for little b it Simplicity.. Thank again